# Do Bitcoin futures contracts affect Bitcoin price?

Tags: exchange-rate, futures

Since Bitcoin futures are cash settled, no Bitcoin are actually exchanged at the time of the expiration of the contract.  Can one assume that since no Bitcoin are exchanged, then Bitcoin supply and demand would not be directly affected and therefore the Bitcoin price would not be affected? If not, then how do futures contracts affect the price?